# How to start highchart column chart from left most corner of x-axis?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

With min and max we can start `line chart` from left most corner of x-axis but that could not apply for `column` and `bar chart`.

For more details please refer this image:
[image: need to start with left most corner]

Can anyone please modify [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/13z2kLcf/) for this solution.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are essentially either workarounds or compromises.

The reason for this is that the column is centered within the category, surrounded by padding, as specified by the `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` properties. This means that there is going to be space on both the left and right side of each column, including the first and last.

**The workaround solution**: Modify your axis `min` and `max` values to cut off the first and last sections of axis.

Code:

```
xAxis: {
    min: 0.25,
    max: data.length -1.25
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/13z2kLcf/2/

Output:

[image: screenshot]

**The compromise solution**: remove your `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`.

Code:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    }
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/13z2kLcf/3/

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution could be to adjust the y-axis by setting a negative `offset`. But i think this is just a workaround. There might be more elegant solutions.

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    /* make all y-axis gridlines invisible */
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    offset: -50//negative offset
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Jérôme, with `offset` option column moved to left but its overlap yAxis labels. please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gauravr/13z2kLcf/6/) with the same.